# Lenovo Ideapad z510 crashes when connected to AC power but works fine with the battery

Tags: windows-8.1, power-supply, battery, lenovo-laptop

I use a [Lenovo Ideapad z510](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/z-series/z510/#tab-tech_specs) running Windows 8 x64 and earlier today, during a snowstorm, power went out. Later, power came back and I got on my computer. As I was using it, I — idiotically — lightly smashed my hands on the keyboard and my computer crashed.

I could only turn it on when running off of battery power only. Trying to turn it on with the plug in would either:

1. Not let it turn on.
2. Crash the computer a few seconds after turning on.

I have tried draining the battery then turning it on with the plug but it doesn’t seem to help. Running from battery works fine, however, I am having issues charging said battery. One of two things is happening right now:

1. The battery is not charging at all, even when plugged into computer that is turned off
2. The battery is charging *very* slowly when plugged into computer that is turned off

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Careful with this. I think it's only a short-term fix...

I fixed it and wanted to post the answer for others. Here is what I did:

*This may not work if your laptop cannot run without a battery. If that is the case, you may try to follow the steps but skip step two. I do not know what this will produce, however, as I have not tried it.*

1. Open up your laptop and **unseat the battery**. This simply means to disconnect it from the laptop, not necessarily to take it out of the case itself.
2. **Start up** the laptop plugged in but **without the battery**. Wait for it to finish booting up; make sure nothing unusual happens.
3. **Shut it down** and then **reseat**, or re-connect **the battery**
4. **Start up** the laptop.

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks. Wouldn't want to have someone messing around inside the computer as it is running :P

Answer (score 1):

Quelklef's answer fixed it for like a month, then it was back to normal.

What I ended up doing now was replacing the entire AC connector. Went to the electronics store and bought a 5-pin connector, cut the ac cable and somehow connected the two. Works perfectly stable for a couple of days now.
It could however be that your problem is not the power connector, so obviously this won't help in that case. Also, please don't burn your house down by not knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Please let your answer provide a solution to OP

Comment: No idea what you mean, as I provided a potential solution.

Comment: You did not answer properly

Comment: And what exactly is missing to be a proper answer?

Comment: Look at Quelklef answer, no comment, no jokes and take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I don't get it. I indirectly stated that I have the same problem, then rougly explained what I did to fix it. If anything, I should get kudos for remembering something that I read months before, and deciding to share my results.